# Toyota FJ Cruiser transmission problem

Tags: toyota, transmission

Got Toyota FJ Cruiser 2010 Automatic, 4x4 full stock (no warranty, I live in Central Europe). I have strange transmission issues. I had already spent 2,5 years of life and about 2500$ just to diagnose the problem, but so far nothing. The problems started when I've got only 3000 km on the odometer.

So the problem(s) are:

- Shifting between all gears occurs with jerks. It occurs when gears up-shift or down-shift. But phenomenon is inconsistent. One time you can accelerate, and get rough shifting between all gears to achieve 5<sup>th</sup> gear (or down-shifts while slowing down). Next time when you accelerate you get rough shifting only between 1-2, 2-3 and 4-5 gears or all together (or any other combination). Next time there maybe no problems at all: absolutely smooth up-shifting. Any combination is possible.
- When you depress gas pedal while moving at any speed and then press it again (even very gently and slowly): there will be jerk forward. Driving car in traffic jam became nearly impossible for me.
- Hard engine braking. It occurs even when road goes downhill. When I shift to neutral car immediately goes faster. So the problem is not in brakes.
- Hard kick down. For example when I drive at 5<sup>th</sup> gear (70 mph) and do kick down, transmission is trying to go through all gears while down-shifting. I mean that there is no shifting from 5<sup>th</sup> to 3<sup>nd</sup> when kick down occurs (normally). It tries to shift 5-4-3.
- When my car stops on steep incline it easily rolls back. Even when compared with other FJs.

Cold or hot weather, cold or hot engine and transmission, sunny or snowy — all the same, problem is present.

What I had already done to diagnose:

- Checked transmission oil level many times — normal.
- Full computer diagnostics — no error codes, nothing.
- Reset ECM (ECU) memory many times — nothing.
- Checked all sensors in transmission using Techstream program — nothing.
- Changed transmission oil and filter on 20000 km (all OEM) — nothing. Oil was very clean.
- Checked transmission oil pressure — nothing.
- Checked engine gasoline system pressure.
- Checked brakes and ABS system many times. Changed brake fluid. Checked parking brake — nothing.
- Changed spark plugs (OEM).
- Cleared MAF sensor.
- Cleared injectors.
- Cleared and checked throttle.
- Checked and greased Cardan shaft.
- Upgraded ECM software — all the problems gone! But in 25 minutes all happened again and still present.
- Bought and installed new ECM — and again only 25 minutes of happiness.

HELP

Comment: Welcome to Mechanics.SE. I formatted the post, and while it is in moderation, I have couple questions. Why is there choke on EFI-equipped vehicle? Is it something else you had meant? How do you perform kick-down on an automatic transmission? Is there a specific kick-down function on this vehicle? Why would you want to kick-down from 5th to 2nd at 70 mph? BTW, is it mph or km/h? Is engine braking really that bad? You sure you do not have lowered gear engaged (which is helpful to slow the car down when going downhill)?

Comment: 1. I am sorry for mistake. I mean throttle, not choke. 2. Nothing special about kick down. When my car was OK there was no hard kick down, it was almost impossible to feel gears downshifting. I checked other FJ's 2010 - everything is OK, different from mine now. 2. If to speak about 70 miles/hour - its just an example. Same hard downshifting while kick down occurs in any other speeds. 3. No. No lower gear engaging while going downhill. Other FJ don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the SLT and SL1 pressure solenoids.

Anyway, thanks for attention.

Comment: Can you provide more information about this so that someone else who gets in the same situation would have some detailed explanation?

Comment: Just replaced solenoids 35290-34010 (SLT) and 35210-50010 (SL1). Nothing else to say.

Comment: But was there a reason for them to go bad? Is it a common malfunction (bad design), or does it have to do with poor maintenance or special operating conditions? Again, what exactly do they do?

Comment: SLT solenoid is well nown for it's problem with jammig, even in low mileage. SL1 is usually not a problem, but I change it be sure and safety.